# Punctuating nested quotations

Tags: punctuation, capitalization, quotations, exclamation-mark

I am editing a novel and I have some questions on how to punctuate nested quotations (or quotations within quotations).

Here is the first example:

> "I kept saying ‘it’s fake’ and ‘he did this’ over and over, completely
> humiliated, while he just sat there with that look on his face.”

A couple of questions for this one:

1. Now, is it correct to leave the nested quotations uncapitalised? If so, does capitalisation apply when the nested quotations are complete sentences? (These examples could be interpreted either way, I believe.)
2. Since this is a retelling of the original speech, would it be inappropriate to use exclamation marks? Would this depend on which manner the speaker is retelling the nested quotations? For example, would it be more appropriate to leave out exclamation marks if the speaker is retelling the story calmly? If they are imitating someone in a frenzied manner, would that call for exclamation marks?

My second example:

> "Instead he shouted at the top of his lungs, ‘YOU ARE SUCH AN IDIOT!’"

3. Similar to the previous question: Is the full capitalisation of the nested quotation appropriate here? Or would that depend on whether or not the current speaker retelling the story is imitating the shouting?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: For what it's worth, I think the reading could be stronger if you went for indirect speech rather than nesting reported speech. eg 'I kept telling him, over and over that it was fake, that X had done all this, over and over. But he just sat there, with that look on his face. I was completely humiliated.' or maybe in the second one, something like 'Instead he screamed in my face that I was an idiot'. The nested direct speech can be a bit stilted.

Comment: @Spagirl You are probably right when someone is reporting their own speech but when they are reporting someone else's the actual words used can be important. They can indicate many things from poor fluency or education to the speaker's level of aggression.

Comment: @BoldBen Indeed, and I wasn't suggesting that it was a general rule, just that it might make this particular text much punchier.